# Grails create-app error-nothing works out

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, grails

I am trying to create Grails app in Eclipse -Kepler version 4.3.2 but i cannot proceed and it gives me the following error :

```
The command 'GrailsCommand(P/testsample> compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
Command: GrailsCommand(P/testsample> compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies)
---- System.out ----
Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
---- System.err ----
Starting process on d7a407/127.0.0.1
Dumping a stacktrace before killing hanging process ...
2014-07-11 13:08:05
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode):

"Thread-0" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d963000 nid=0x12fc waiting on condition [0x000000002004e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.shared.longrunning.SafeProcess$HeartBeatMonitor.sleep(SafeProcess.java:79)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.shared.longrunning.SafeProcess$HeartBeatMonitor.run(SafeProcess.java:64)

"Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d8d0000 nid=0x16c0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d857000 nid=0x1fac waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d855000 nid=0x15b4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d84a000 nid=0x1298 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d842000 nid=0xbb4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d83e800 nid=0x1b48 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d83c000 nid=0xf4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x00000000025fe000 nid=0x1664 in Object.wait() [0x000000001ebbe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c3288038> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x00000006c3288038> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c784800 nid=0x17a0 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e9ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c3289160> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000006c3289160> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000024ff000 nid=0x1e04 runnable [0x000000000297a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    - locked <0x000000076cb81d78> (a java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:817)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager.collectDependencies(AetherDependencyManager.groovy:515)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager.resolve(AetherDependencyManager.groovy:348)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:775)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:769)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:674)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.getClassLoaderUrls(ClasspathConfigurer.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.configuredClassLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:630)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:613)
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.ensureInitialized(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:157)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c77f800 nid=0x1ab8 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000257c800 nid=0x1f4c runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000257e800 nid=0x1b90 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002580000 nid=0x15cc runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002581800 nid=0x794 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002584800 nid=0x508 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002586000 nid=0x1d00 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002587000 nid=0x195c runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002588000 nid=0x1834 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d8d1000 nid=0x1878 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 83


------System.out:-----------
 Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
------System.err:-----------
Starting process on d7a407/127.0.0.1
Dumping a stacktrace before killing hanging process ...
2014-07-11 13:08:05
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode):

"Thread-0" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d963000 nid=0x12fc waiting on condition [0x000000002004e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.shared.longrunning.SafeProcess$HeartBeatMonitor.sleep(SafeProcess.java:79)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.shared.longrunning.SafeProcess$HeartBeatMonitor.run(SafeProcess.java:64)

"Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d8d0000 nid=0x16c0 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d857000 nid=0x1fac waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d855000 nid=0x15b4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d84a000 nid=0x1298 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d842000 nid=0xbb4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d83e800 nid=0x1b48 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d83c000 nid=0xf4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x00000000025fe000 nid=0x1664 in Object.wait() [0x000000001ebbe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c3288038> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x00000006c3288038> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c784800 nid=0x17a0 in Object.wait() [0x000000001e9ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c3289160> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000006c3289160> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000024ff000 nid=0x1e04 runnable [0x000000000297a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    - locked <0x000000076cb81d78> (a java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:817)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager.collectDependencies(AetherDependencyManager.groovy:515)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.maven.aether.AetherDependencyManager.resolve(AetherDependencyManager.groovy:348)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:514)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:775)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure19.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:769)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:674)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.getClassLoaderUrls(ClasspathConfigurer.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.configuredClassLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:630)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:613)
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.ensureInitialized(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:157)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c77f800 nid=0x1ab8 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000257c800 nid=0x1f4c runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000257e800 nid=0x1b90 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002580000 nid=0x15cc runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002581800 nid=0x794 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002584800 nid=0x508 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002586000 nid=0x1d00 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002587000 nid=0x195c runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002588000 nid=0x1834 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001d8d1000 nid=0x1878 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 83
```

I am using Grails 2.4.2 and jdk 1.8. I tried every possible thing. I tried deleting .m2 and .Grails folders too then also it did not work. Please let me know if anyone has the solution for this.

i downloaded Grails from here : https://grails.org/downloads  which i point to from eclipse
i installed grails plugin in eclipse from here : http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all

Nothing works...please help if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: I'm not using JDK8, but still, have you tried using either Java7 or Java6? Also have you checked if running the same commands outside eclipse produces the same errors?

Comment: Yes i tried using Java7 this time. This time i got the Groovy/Grails Tool Suite. Everything works fine only when i create the project it gets stuck on 50% and gives me the same warning. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What about using the command line?? This could just be an Eclipse or GGTS bug...

Comment: I tried the same steps on my personal laptop , they worked. Do u think there is some firewall issue because it gets stuck at downloading Tomcat phase. it gets everything but when there is configuring classpath, i get this issue whereas in my personal laptop it gives downloading tomcat after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the solution, there were issues with the proxy settings and i was using wrong Groovy version. I should have used Groovy 2.3.4 instead of Groovy 2.4.0.

Also since i was working in internal network, proxy settings required in grails set-proxy myproxy were :

myproxy=["http.proxyHost":"myproxy", "http.proxyPort":"4300", "http.proxyUserName":"proxyuser", "http.proxyPassword":"mypassword"] 
currentProxy="myproxy"